# Allow users to update secrets on a running Streamlit app?

Tags: streamlit

I want to launch a public Streamlit app which uses Google Text-to-Speech and OpenAI API. What I would really want to do is to let users insert **their** API keys to be used with the app.

Is there a way to do that? So far the best solution I have is to have each user clone the app from GitHub and then deploy it with its own secrets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't currently a way to allow end users of the app to set secrets. The best alternative at this point in time is to create a `st.text_input` field to allow users to input their own API key.